# Apply style to all divs except one specific

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply styles to all my divs, except one specific. I'm doing this but it doesn't work:

```css
#toolbar div[class~="olControlNavigationHistory"]{
   float: left;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: 2px 12px 2px 12px;
}
```

So I need to apply this style to all the divs in #toolbar EXCEPT the div with a class called "olControlNavigationHistory".

How can I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply CSS Style on all elements except with a SPECIFIC ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464660/apply-css-style-on-all-elements-except-with-a-specific-id)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just apply the rule to all divs first:

```css
#toolbar div {
   float: left;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: 2px 12px 2px 12px;
}
```

Then you need to zero the values out for the specific case:

```css
#toolbar div.olControlNavigationHistor {
   float: none;
   background-repeat: repeat;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Of course this assumes that the property values that specific div would have had without the first rule applied are each properties defaults (such as `margin: 0` and `float: none`.)

**EDIT:**
However in the future when CSS3 is supported everywere, you could also just rewrite your original rule as `#toolbar div:not(.olControlNavigationHistory)` and it would work correctly and elegantly.

Comment: @user552669 For the record `~=` means contains, not "not equal" - [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). However in the future when CSS3 is supported everywere, you could also just rewrite your original rule as `#toolbar div:not(.olControlNavigationHistory)` and it would work correctly and elegantly.

Answer (score 5):

I was just doing the same and found this answer
Use the :not selector:

```css
div:not(#div1){
    color:red;
}
```

it was posted in [Apply CSS Style on all elements except with a SPECIFIC ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464660/apply-css-style-on-all-elements-except-with-a-specific-id)