# Apply CSS Style on all elements except with a SPECIFIC ID

Tags: html, css

### CSS Code(what I need)

```
<style>
    div[id!='div1']// I actually needed an inequality operator for NOT EQUAL TO
    {
        font-size:40px;
    }
</style>
```

### HTML code

```
<body>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div id='div1'>ghi</div>
</body>
```

The CSS didn't work as I intended.

I actually wanted to define the style for all `<div>`-elements except the one with `id='div1'`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Anot) selector:

```css
div:not(#bar){
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar</div>
```

---

Update : `name` instead of `ID`:

```css
div:not([name="bar"]){
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div name="bar">bar</div>
```

---

Update: **CSS2 selector**, similar answer to *Tom Heard-s*:

```css
div{
    color:red;
}

div[name="bar"]{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div name="bar">bar</div>
```

Also, see [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

Comment: vucko, I am pleased to get a solution. But if I had to check it say on the basis of the `name` instead of `id` attribute then what should I do???

Comment: @RajeshPaul you're welcome. `:not` selector is a **CSS3** selector so it's not supported by **IE8 or less**, see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).

Comment: So is there any way for the `name`-check using CSS2?

Comment: @RajeshPaul it is if you use a JS plugin like [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Comment: @Vucko Your Js fiddle is not working, can you please update it.

Answer (score 20):

CSS3 solution:

```
div:not(#div1)
```

CSS2 solution:

```
div {
    color: red;
}

div#div1 {
    color: inherit;
}
```

By name:

CSS3 solution:

```
div:not([name=div1]) {
    color: red;
}
```

CSS2 Solution (note not supported in IE6 - but who cares anymore):

```
div {
    color: red;
}

div[name=div1] {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Tom, Coincidentally I asked for `id`-validation. But say I needed to check an inequality on the `name`-attribute of the element, then what should I do?

Comment: why it doesn't work for me in `*:not(#email)`, that is, when used for all elements

Comment: @nakinlaulu I have no idea why that doesn't work (it doesn't for me either) but you can do something like `body *:not(#email)` and it will work. See http://jsfiddle.net/1ty8ns3k/1, sorry I couldn't give a better answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are only to target browsers supporting CSS3 selectors you could do this:

```
div:not(#div1) {
...my styles...
}
```