# Set CSS style on all but specific page ID

Tags: css, styling

I'm working on a site for a client that wants to use a specific background color site-wide EXCEPT on one page that's basically used as a separate 1-page website with unique content & styling.

My question is this... how can I apply a CSS style to all BUT a specific page ID?

My CSS currently looks like this:

```
.et_section_regular, #main-content {background-color: #F5EFE5 !important}
```

The !important is there because I'm having to override the themes default background color to begin with. I've tried using the following not: selector ([referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464660/apply-css-style-on-all-elements-except-with-a-specific-id)) with no luck:

```
.et_section_regular:not (.page-id-714 .et_section_regular), #main-content:not(.page-id-714 #main-content) {background-color: #F5EFE5 !important}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Show us some of the HTML as well. Not sure what the structure is you are working with.

Comment: Don't use `!important` in that situation. (Better don't use it at all - IMO every thing can be solved without it). Go with stronger selectors. Your overriding rules would need to be as "selective" as the strongest `!important` rule and must be defined after that. IMO, `not()` is not necessary: `.page-123 .class .class {...}` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/cPPwt/1/)**

You cannot choose selectors that are above the selection where you apply `:not()`

An alternative is to first mention parent selection where your page id is applied then target the inner div's - Check the demo.

**CSS:**

```
section:not(.page-id-174) .et_section_regular,
section:not(.page-id-174) #main-content{
    background-color: #F5EFE5 !important
}
```

Note i am using section tag just for the DEMO but you can use body tag - where i assume you have your `.page-id-174` applied

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried this, replacing "section" with "body" and wasn't able to make it work, either in your demo or on my site. So maybe body won't work there?

body:not(.page-id-174) .et_section_regular, body:not(.page-id-174) #main-content{background-color: #F5EFE5 !important}

Comment: Thanks again all for the feedback. I finally gave up trying to do it this way and just created a new page template and styled it that way. Hopefully this little thread will be helpful to someone else down the road though - maybe someone smarter than me that can figure out how to implement Imran's suggestion.

Comment: there was no need to create different template you could have used the power of hierarchy checmk my [answer revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24101175/revisions)

Comment: I have just confirmed my current solution works even with body tag... you must be having some other issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's just an issue with the particular theme and structure I'm using (Elegant Themes Divi). By targeting the templateid I was able to simplify this and avoid having to use the :not. Thank you for your time, will definitely bookmark this for later!