# How to exclude a CSS selector from applying to elements inside a class?

Tags: css

```
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, 
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, 
sup, sub, tt, var, u, i, center, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, tfoot, caption, form, fieldset, 
legend, input, button, textarea, select, label, applet, object, iframe, audio, video, 
canvas, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, 
nav, section, summary {
    font-family: inherit; line-height: inherit; 
    vertical-align: baseline; border: 0; outline: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

I don't want that to effect any elements inside `div.base`.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: "I believe OP wants for the declaration he included in his question to apply to all cases, but NOT to children of div.base – Patrick Moore "

Comment: just rewrite those properties for `div.base` with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Try the :[not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector.

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, has a functional notation taking a simple selector `X` as an argument. It matches elements that are not represented by the argument. `X` must not contain another negation selector. (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not))

`* { }` Styles all the elements. Adding `:not(.base)` to it excludes elements with class base.

```
*:not(#div1){
    color:red;
}
```

Example:

```css
*:not(.base) {
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div>
    <h1 class="base">Text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think it works if he wants to only target divs with class name `base`

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule which resets each of those properties for elements in `div.base`:

```
div.base * {
    font-family: initial; line-height: initial; 
    vertical-align: initial; border: initial; outline: initial; padding: initial; margin: initial;
}
```

> The `initial` CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. —[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how do I apply a single CSS property or set of properties to everything then you can do this.

```
   * {
      font-family: inherit; 
      line-height: inherit; 
      vertical-align: baseline; 
      border: 0; 
      outline: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      margin: 0;
    }
   div.base {
    #set properties for div.base here
   }
```

Comment: I believe OP wants for the declaration he included in his question to apply to all cases, but NOT to children of `div.base`

Comment: Did you read the question? This is clearly NOT what they want

Comment: He can override the style on `div.base` I'll edit to show.

Comment: @AndrewLi how is it NOT what they want?

Comment: @MikeTung Before your edit, it wasn't what they wanted. You just assumed their question.

Comment: It's not an assumption, since the goal was to edit everything. Also if OP had any basic understanding of CSS he would know he can override. So again how is `This is NOT what they want`?

Comment: "I believe OP wants for the declaration he included in his question to apply to all cases, but NOT to children of div.base – Patrick Moore "

that's exactly what i need

Comment: you may refer with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464660/apply-css-style-on-all-elements-except-with-a-specific-id