# How to apply class style on everything but a specific class and its children?( Nested Theme )

Tags: css, less

**html**

```html
<ul class="style-b">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two
    <ul>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item Three
    <ul class="style-a">
      <li>3.1
        <ul>
          <li>3.1.1</li>
          <li>3.1.2</li>
          <li>3.1.3
            <ul class="style-b">
              <li>3.1.3.1</li>
              <li>3.1.3.2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**less**

```less
.style-b {
  li {
    color: rebeccapurple;
  }
}
.style-a {
  li {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

**result img**
[result-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PRdb.png)
The `.style-a` has higher priority so that the nested `.style-b` doesn't work.
I simplify the css style to one-level nesting `li` style,actually it has multiple nested class in my project.

I have tried to use `:not()` to exclude another,but seems compound selectors inside is prohibited.

```less
.style-b *:not(.style-a *) {
  li {
    color: rebeccapurple;
  }
}
.style-a *:not(.style-b *) {
  li {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

I am now adding another class `.important` to improve the priority,and add `important` in nested one.
But it can only support two-level nesting,and is really foolish.

```less
._styleA() {
  li {
    color: black;
  }
}
._styleB() {
  li {
    color: rebeccapurple;
  }
}
.style-a {
  ._styleA()
}
.style-a.important {
  ._styleA()
}
.style-b {
  ._styleB()
}
.style-b.important {
  ._styleB()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply CSS Style on all elements except with a SPECIFIC ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464660/apply-css-style-on-all-elements-except-with-a-specific-id)

Comment: @Rob It doesn't help when the class style works on its children instead of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out that my question is how to realize nested theme. I found the react UI frame `ant design`'s nested theme satisfied my needs. And i will realize a same one myself.

see [css-var-plan of ant design](https://ant-design.antgroup.com/docs/blog/css-var-plan)

Comment: You do not need to answer yourself you can add it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `style-b` like this `ul.style-b > li`

```css
ul.style-b > li {
    color: rebeccapurple;
}

.style-a li {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="style-b">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two
    <ul>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item Three
    <ul class="style-a">
      <li>3.1
        <ul>
          <li>3.1.1</li>
          <li>3.1.2</li>
          <li>3.1.3
            <ul class="style-b">
              <li>3.1.3.1</li>
              <li>3.1.3.2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to use `style-a` and `style-b` as theme style class,not fixed nested like `style-b`->`style-a`->`style-b`,but every possible nesting order.